# Openmeetings: problem in running: "Address already in use "

Tags: linux, video, java, centos, conferencing

i am trying to run openmeetings in my CentOS vps.

when i run

```
$ ./red5.sh
```

after a lot of lines it says:

```
Bootstrap Complete
```

and a few lines before it it says:

```
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
...
```

i have tried red5.sh with root and a nomral user. both gives error like that.

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem.

my vps uses PLESK and it makes port **8443** budy.

i just changed 8443 to some thing else in **conf/red5.properties**

it passed from that line, but it stopped somewhere else.

Comment: i finally ran it completely!